# Install CKeditor5 in Symfony5

Tags: ckeditor5, symfony5

I would like to install CKeditor5 for symfony5.

```
composer require friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle

php bin/console ckeditor:install
```

This gives me CKeditor4 ...

Is it possible to use CKeditor5, if possible a custom version generated using the online generator CKEditor as was the case with CKedtor4 ...

Thank you :).

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can do that.

https://symfony.com/doc/1.0/bundles/FOSCKEditorBundle/usage/ckeditor.html#ckeditor-version

So instead of running:

```
php bin/console ckeditor:install
```

Your do:

```
$ php bin/console ckeditor:install --tag=
```

So in your tag you can define the version you want.

You might want to try the tags avaiable in the ckeditor official repo to get to the one you want.

https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/tags

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible to download the Ckeditor created using the online builder?  With CKeditor4, we did:`

`php bin/console ckeditor:insta
ll --release=custom --custom-build-id=your_id


`

Comment: This will not work because the command try to retrieve a v4 release from the repo and not v5, for me the only way to get ckeditor v5 is to install it without bundle.